# How to access data of a pivot table ( many to many relationship laravel )

Tags: php, laravel, oop, web

I'm trying to get data from pivot table and passing them with jquery ajax. I want to get the name of the book and the quantity of its.

My Model

```
class Order extends Model
{
    public function books(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class)->withPivot('quantity');
    }

}


class Book extends Model
{

    public function order(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class)->withPivot('quantity');
    }

}
```

This is my controller

```
public function detail($id){
        if($id){
            $order = Order::find($id);
            dd($order->books);
        }
    }
```

I dont know why it returned

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#350 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

My pivot table (book_order)

```
id | order_id | book_id | quantity
```

Comment: does this order have books?

Answer (score -1):

> You may retrieve the `quantity` column from the `book_order` pivot table by using :

```
class Order extends Model
{
    public function books(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class)
        ->withPivot([
            'quantity',
        ]);
    }
}


class Book extends Model
{
    public function order(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class)
        ->withPivot([
            'quantity',
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
//Controller
public function detail($id){
   if($id){
      //Eager Load
      $orderWithBooks = Order::with('books')->find($id);
      foreach ($order->books as $book) {
         $quantity = $book->pivot->quantity;
         dump($quantity);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Regarding laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships withPivot must hold pivot model name, but i think quantity is an attribute inside pivot table

Answer (score -1):

Basically, I assumed you have table like this :

```
**books** 
id 
name

**orders** 
id 

**quantity**
book_id
order_id
```

Models :

```
class Order extends Model
{
    public function books(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class,'quantity');
    }

}

class Book extends Model
{

    public function orders(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class,'quantity');
    }

}
```

Try to get relation like this :

```
$books = $order->books()->get();
```

Comment: I guess quantity is a column inside the pivot table